# Anki2 CSS: Hideable "empty fields" wrapped in fancy boxes

Tags: html, css, anki

So i have 3 answer fields on the back of my cloze cards: "Verb", "Dativ" and "Akkusativ". I have tweaked the css a lil and wrapped each field inside a box using div tag. With each card comes the verb with either Dativ or Akkusativ. So, for instance the Verb and Akkusativ fields have an input and the Dativ field remains empty.

***I need to know if there's a way to hide the field without any entries aka the empty field*** which is wrapped up in a box. I've already tried the **":empty"** and **":blank"** pseudo selectors, but they would hide and show both of the fields respectively no matter if they are empty or they contain text, img ,etc.

Screenshot: https://ibb.co/jLtvvw
Fullcode: https://uploadfiles.io/zpeq8

Here's the css and html for the boxes:
Css:

```
.box2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background: #f4bf42;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #6d4500;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
box-shadow: 0px 8px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   font-family: arialblack;
}

.box3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background: #5ec9ff;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #005b89;
 text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
box-shadow: 0px 8px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   font-family: arialblack;
}
```

Back Template:

```
<div class="box2">
{{Dativ}}
</div>

<div class="box3">
{{Akkusativ}}
</div>
```